# Use int 2d array to count char array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, count, row

I didn't finish it yet, the question in named getRows() metthod, I just try use a int [][]counts to count how much X in char [][] array every rows, and print it out. I did something wrong, there isnt work.

```
package labassignment6;

import java.util.Random;

public class LabAssignment6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size;
        char array[][];
        Random randy = new Random();

        for (size = 4; size <= 6; size++) {
            //fill the array with random X O or space
            array = fillArray(size, randy);

            //print array
            System.out.println("\nsize" + size);
            printArray(array);

            doRows(array);
//            1.method to doRows which call
//                -method with loops to count X and Os in each row
//                -methos print each row's counts
            //doColumns(array);
//            2.method to doColumns which call
//                -method with loops to count per column
//                -method to print each column's counts
            //doDiagonals(array);
//            3.method to doDiagonals which calls
//                -method with single loop to count top left to bottom right and
//                    another sigle loop to count top right to bottom left
//                -method to print diagonal's counts

        }//end outer array size loop

    }

    public static char[][] fillArray(int size, Random randy) {
        int row = 0, col = 0, N;
        char i = ' ';
        char array[][];
        // create array
        array = new char[size][size];
        //code inside loops to choose X, O or space with weighting

        for (row = 0; row < size; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < size; col++) {
                N = randy.nextInt(5);
                if (N == 0 || N == 1) {
                    i = 'X';
                } else if (N == 2 || N == 3) {
                    i = 'O';
                } else {
                    i = ' ';
                }
                array[row][col] = i;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        return array;
    }

    public static void printArray(char array[][]) {
        int row, col;
        for (row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(array[row][col] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    public static void doRows(char array[][]) {
        int counts[][];
        //counts = new int [0][2];
        counts = new int[array.length - 1][array.length - 1];
        getRows(array, counts);
//    printRows(array, counts);
    }

    public static void getRows(char array[][], int counts[][]) {
//        int x = 0, o = 0, s = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
                if (i<array[j].length && array[i][j] == 'X') {
                    counts[i][0]++;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Row " + i + " has " + counts[i][1] + " X");

        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you see when you step through the code in your debugger?  What do you mean by "doesn't work" (I assume that is what you meant) ?  What does it do?  What should it do?

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, `counts` counts the number of matches in each row.  Therefore, there should be one value for each row, which would mean `counts` should be a one-dimensional array, not two-dimensional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved your ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception - which was being caused by:

```
counts = new int[array.length - 1][array.length - 1];
```

The counts array size was being set too small. It needs to be the same size as the length of the original array, or it ends up being one size too small.

However, as ajb mentioned, count[][] should actually be a one-dimensional array. If you look at your code, you can see that you are only using count[i][0] - so basically, you're using it almost as if it is a one-dimensional array - since you are only using one index for each value of i. So you could just use count[i] instead of count[i][0] and it would do the same thing. The two-dimensional approach certainly may work, and may serve to teach you interesting ways to use two-dimensional arrays. But generally speaking, the simpler approach is often the better approach. K.I.S.S. :)

Your problems mostly exist in the getRows function. You increment the value of counts[i][0] in each iteration of the inner loop, but then when outputting the number of X's in each row, you use the value counts[i][1] - which never gets set to anything (since you only use counts[i][0], not counts[i][1]) and is 0 by default. And by the way, in the if statement in the inner loop, you don't need to check if i < length. The outer for loop already checks for that condition, and i isn't being incremented anywhere within the loops, it is only incremented by one after each loop is executed - and then the test condition checks if it is less than array.length again. So it is redundant to check that in the if statement - it will always return true unless you increment i somewhere within the body of the loop.

Here is a working version of getRows:

```
public static void getRows(char array[][], int counts[][]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
            if (array[i][j] == 'X') {
                counts[i][0]++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Row " + i + " has " + counts[i][0] + " X");
    }
}
```

However, as you can see, you really should be using a one-dimensional array - even though this program does work properly. I will repost the entire program again soon using a one dimensional array. Should only take a minute.

Comment: Thanks u so much, I change counts = new int[array.length - 1][array.length - 1]; to counts = new int[array.length ][array.length];,and change other it works,thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I'll just give him the entire working code for the program. I hope this answers the question:

```
package labassignment6;
import java.util.*;

public class LabAssignment6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size;
        char array[][];
        Random randy = new Random();

        for (size = 4; size <= 6; size++) {
            //fill the array with random X O or space
            array = fillArray(size, randy);

            //print array
            System.out.println("\nsize: " + size);
            printArray(array);

            doRows(array);

        }

    }

    public static char[][] fillArray(int size, Random randy) {
        int row = 0, col = 0, N;
        char i = ' ';
        char array[][];
        // create array
        array = new char[size][size];

        for (row = 0; row < size; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < size; col++) {
                N = randy.nextInt(5);
                if (N == 0 || N == 1) {
                    i = 'X';
                } else if (N == 2 || N == 3) {
                    i = 'O';
                } else {
                    i = ' ';
                }
                array[row][col] = i;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        return array;
    }

    public static void printArray(char array[][]) {
        int row, col;
        for (row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(array[row][col] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void doRows(char array[][]) {
        int counts[];
        counts = new int[array.length];
        getRows(array, counts);
    }

    public static void getRows(char array[][], int counts[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
                if (array[i][j] == 'X') {
                    counts[i]++;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Row " + i + " has " + counts[i] + " X");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know if change int count[][] to count[] its more smart, but my TA don't want we change it...

Comment: That's most unfortunate. Your TA is teaching you bad coding habits. At least you're aware of it though.